# Uploading a file to AdonisJS via Input type="file"

Tags: html, reactjs, file-upload, next.js, adonis.js

I am trying to upload a file from an input type="file". Here is how I get the input:

`<input type="file" onChange={(e) => setFile(e.target.files)}/>`

Then, when I log it, I get this:

[Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9DTQ.png)

However, when I try to send it to my Adonis server, I will get an error 422, and this message:

`{"errors":[{"rule":"required","field":"image","message":"required validation failed"}]}`

Here is the validator:

`image: schema.file({ size: '5mb', extnames: ['jpg', 'png', 'jpeg'] })`

I am quite lost as to what is causing this, I do not see any other way to send the file, or send the binary data of the file. Any help and explication would be much appreciated!

Side-note: I did all of this following the Adonis doc for the backend side, so that should be good, altough I may be wrong.
Also, I am only looking for storing the files locally as of now.

There wasn't much I could try, since I couldn't find any other way to upload a file to an Adonis server. I did check if the file was following the validator rules, which it is (a .jpg file of 28Kb)

Edit: I got it working if I use postman and that I input directly a file that way, which means that my html is not working. Any ideas how I could reproduce the way that postman send a file ?

Answer (score 0):

For those wondering, I fix the error by sending a POST request with a form-data rather than simply an object that I parsed into a JSON. This fixed the issue.